# How to calculate average with quarterly interval within a year?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I would like to calculate average of some values within a year from daily data.

I normally do that in excel by utilizing EDATE function, so for example if today is *June 21, 2019*, I can set the interval with respect to month easily. But, I couldn't find the equivalent of this function in Python.

Let's say I have this data:

```
 Date         Price    
 03-Jan-11    112
 04-Jan-11    115
 05-Jan-11    116
 06-Jan-11    111
 etc
```

And, what I'm trying to do is to calculate the average on *3-Jan-11*, with EDATE excel function, it should calculate the average from date of *1-Apr-11* (3 months), *1-Jul-11* (6 months), *3-Oct-11* (9 months) and *3-Jan-12* (12 months). And, the rule is also applicable for the next date i.e. 4-Jan-11. Is there any way that I can do this kind of calculation on Python?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  My thinking is that you're either going to need to find a Python library that does this sort of calculation, or you're going to need to write the code to do this yourself.  Such code would not be difficult to write for a seasoned programmer.  In the first case, this question is off-topic for this site.  In the second, it is too broad for this site.  In either case, to get real help here, you should get further along in coming up with your own solution (via either option).  Once you have something, show it to us here to get help when you run into trouble.

Comment: Hi Steve, well to be honest I have no clue, I'm self-taught and very new at this. Do you have any reference where I can pick up the knowledge? Many thanks. @Steve

Comment: So is this data a pandas data frame, a list of values, a string, a csv, an excel sheet, ...?

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi , this is a pandas data frame. Would you mind to share some insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give some example whats the output you are looking for and also possibly some more data points.

Meanwhile, though I didn't quite understand what you are expecting. I am guessing you are looking for something like this.

```
d = {'Date': ['03-Jan-11', '04-Jan-11', '05-Jan-11', '06-Jan-11', '12-Mar-11', '05-Apr-11', '08-Jul-11', '05-Jan-12'], 
     'Price': [112, 115, 116, 111, 120, 118, 125, 114]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.Date, freq='Q')

df.groupby(['quarter']).mean()

 out put       
quarter Price
2011Q1  114.8
2011Q2  118.0
2011Q3  125.0
2012Q1  114.0
```

let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi @Vishwas, the actual data is not here, I'm only displaying the preview of the data. So, for 3-Jan-11, I want to take average value from 1-Apr-11, 1-Jul-11, 3-Oct-11 and 3-Jan-12, which has 3 month interval each. And, the result should be appended on new column. Looking forward to your feedback